# Extracting a nest dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to extract nested dicts into my data frame, the data is current stored in a column in the data frame and struggling too extract in to the row with attributes as column headers. I have tried breaking it down further to stats from data but get errors. Can anyone help please?

```
text_last5610 = responseteamlast5610.content
tree_last5610 = json.loads(text_last5610)
d_last5610 = tree_last5610["data"]
df_last5610 = pd.DataFrame(d_last5610)
df_last5610.head()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWQit.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBcnS.png)

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "alt_names": [
                "The Clarets"
            ],
            "competition_id": -1,
            "continent": null,
            "country": "England",
            "english_name": "Burnley FC",
            "founded": "1882",
            "full_name": "Burnley FC",
            "id": 145,
            "image": "https://cdn.footystats.org/img/teams/england-burnley-fc.png",
            "last_updated_match_timestamp": 1639317600,
            "last_x_home_away_or_overall": "0",
            "last_x_match_num": 5,
            "name": "Burnley",
            "official_sites": [
                "https://www.burnleyfootballclub.com/"
            ],
            "performance_rank": 0,
            "risk": 60,
            "season": "2021",
            "season_format": "Domestic League",
            "stats": {
                "AVGHT_away": 0.67,
                "AVGHT_home": 2.5,
                "AVGHT_overall": 1.4,
                "AVG_2hg_away": 0.33,
                "AVG_2hg_home": 0.5,
                "AVG_2hg_overall": 0.4,
                "BTTS_and_draw_away": 1,
                "BTTS_and_draw_home": 1,
                "BTTS_and_draw_overall": 2,
                "BTTS_and_draw_percentage_away": 33,
                "BTTS_and_draw_percentage_home": 50,
                "BTTS_and_draw_percentage_overall": 40,
                "BTTS_and_lose_away": 0,
                "BTTS_and_lose_home": 0,
                "BTTS_and_lose_overall": 0,
                "BTTS_and_lose_percentage_away": 0,
                "BTTS_and_lose_percentage_home": 0,
                "BTTS_and_lose_percentage_overall": 0,
                "BTTS_and_win_away": 0,
                "BTTS_and_win_home": 0,
                "BTTS_and_win_overall": 0,
                "BTTS_and_win_percentage_away": 0,
                "BTTS_and_win_percentage_home": 0,
                "BTTS_and_win_percentage_overall": 0,
                "BTTS_both_halves_away": 0,
                "BTTS_both_halves_home": 0,
                "BTTS_both_halves_overall": 0,
                "BTTS_both_halves_percentage_away": 0,
                "BTTS_both_halves_percentage_home": 0,
                "BTTS_both_halves_percentage_overall": 0,
                "GoalDifferenceHT_away": -2,
                "GoalDifferenceHT_home": -1,
                "GoalDifferenceHT_overall": -3,
                "GoalsHT_away": 2,
                "GoalsHT_home": 5,
                "GoalsHT_overall": 7,
                "HTPPG_away": 0.33,
                "HTPPG_home": 0.5,
                "HTPPG_overall": 0.4,
                "HTPoints_away": 1,
                "HTPoints_home": 1,
                "HTPoints_overall": 2,
                "additional_info": {
                    "2h_cards_against_avg_away": 1,
                    "2h_cards_against_avg_home": 1.5,
                    "2h_cards_against_avg_overall": 1.2,
                    "2h_cards_against_away": 3,
                    "2h_cards_against_home": 3,
                    "2h_cards_against_overall": 6,
                    "2h_cards_for_avg_away": 2,
                    "2h_cards_for_avg_home": 0.5,
                    "2h_cards_for_avg_overall": 1.4,
                    "2h_cards_for_away": 6,
                    "2h_cards_for_home": 1,
                    "2h_cards_for_over05_percentage_away": 100,
                    "2h_cards_for_over05_percentage_home": 50,
                    "2h_cards_for_over05_percentage_overall": 80,
                    "2h_cards_for_overall": 7,
                    "2h_cards_total_avg_away": 3,
                    "2h_cards_total_avg_home": 2,
                    "2h_cards_total_avg_overall": 2.6,
                    "2h_cards_total_away": 9,
                    "2h_cards_total_home": 4,
                    "2h_cards_total_overall": 13,
                    "2h_half_with_most_cards_total_percentage_away": 67,
                    "2h_half_with_most_cards_total_percentage_home": 50,
                    "2h_half_with_most_cards_total_percentage_overall": 60,
                    "2h_total_cards_2to3_percentage_away": 67,
                    "2h_total_cards_2to3_percentage_home": 50,
                    "2h_total_cards_2to3_percentage_overall": 60,
                    "2h_total_cards_over3_percentage_away": 33,
                    "2h_total_cards_over3_percentage_home": 0,
                    "2h_total_cards_over3_percentage_overall": 20,
                    "2h_total_cards_under2_percentage_away": 0,
                    "2h_total_cards_under2_percentage_home": 50,
                    "2h_total_cards_under2_percentage_overall": 20,
                    "attack_num_recoded_matches_away": 3,
                    "attack_num_recoded_matches_home": 1,
                    "attacks_num_away": 302,
                    "attacks_num_home": 103,
                    "btts_1h2h_no_no_num_away": 3,
                    "btts_1h2h_no_no_num_home": 1,
                    "btts_1h2h_no_no_num_overall": 4,
                    "btts_1h2h_no_no_percentage_away": 100,
                    "btts_1h2h_no_no_percentage_home": 50,
                    "btts_1h2h_no_no_percentage_overall": 80,
                    "btts_1h2h_no_yes_num_away": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_no_yes_num_home": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_no_yes_num_overall": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_no_yes_percentage_away": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_no_yes_percentage_home": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_no_yes_percentage_overall": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_yes_no_num_away": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_yes_no_num_home": 1,
                    "btts_1h2h_yes_no_num_overall": 1,
                    "btts_1h2h_yes_no_percentage_away": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_yes_no_percentage_home": 50,
                    "btts_1h2h_yes_no_percentage_overall": 20,
                    "btts_1h2h_yes_yes_num_away": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_yes_yes_num_home": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_yes_yes_num_overall": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_yes_yes_percentage_away": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_yes_yes_percentage_home": 0,
                    "btts_1h2h_yes_yes_percentage_overall": 0,
                    "cardTimingRecorded_matches_away": 3,
                    "cardTimingRecorded_matches_home": 2,
                    "cardTimingRecorded_matches_overall": 5,
                    "cardsRecorded_matches_away": 3,
                    "cardsRecorded_matches_home": 2,
                    "cardsRecorded_matches_overall": 5,
                    "cards_against_avg_away": 1.33,
                    "cards_against_avg_home": 2,
                    "cards_against_avg_overall": 1.6,
                    "cards_against_away": 4,
                    "cards_against_home": 4,
                    "cards_against_overall": 8,
                    "cards_for_avg_away": 2.67,
                    "cards_for_avg_home": 2,
                    "cards_for_avg_overall": 2.4,
                    "cards_for_away": 8,
                    "cards_for_home": 4,
                    "cards_for_overall": 12,
                    "cards_total_avg_away": 4,
                    "cards_total_avg_home": 4,
                    "cards_total_avg_overall": 4,
                    "cards_total_away": 12,
                    "cards_total_home": 8,
                    "cards_total_overall": 20,
                    "corners_earned_1h_2_to_3_num_away": 1,
                    "corners_earned_1h_2_to_3_num_home": 0,
                    "corners_earned_1h_2_to_3_num_overall": 1,
                    "corners_earned_1h_2_to_3_percentage_away": 33,
                    "corners_earned_1h_2_to_3_percentage_home": 0,
                    "corners_earned_1h_2_to_3_percentage_overall": 25,
                    "corners_earned_1h_avg_away": 1.67,
                    "corners_earned_1h_avg_home": 1,
                    "corners_earned_1h_avg_overall": 1.5,
                    "corners_earned_1h_num_away": 5,
                    "corners_earned_1h_num_home": 1,
                    "corners_earned_1h_num_overall": 6,
                    "corners_earned_1h_over2_num_away": 1,
                    "corners_earned_1h_over2_num_home": 0,
                    "corners_earned_1h_over2_num_overall": 1,
                    "corners_earned_1h_over2_percentage_away": 33,
                    "corners_earned_1h_over2_percentage_home": 0,
                    "corners_earned_1h_over2_percentage_overall": 25,
                    "corners_earned_1h_over3_num_away": 0,
                    "corners_earned_1h_over3_num_home": 0,
                    "corners_earned_1h_over3_num_overall": 0,
                    "corners_earned_1h_over3_percentage_away": 0,
                    "corners_earned_1h_over3_percentage_home": 0,
                    "corners_earned_1h_over3_percentage_overall": 0,
                    "corners_earned_2h_2_to_3_num_away": 2,
                    "corners_earned_2h_2_to_3_num_home": 1,
                    "corners_earned_2h_2_to_3_num_overall": 3,
                    "corners_earned_2h_2_to_3_percentage_away": 67,
                    "corners_earned_2h_2_to_3_percentage_home": 100,
                    "corners_earned_2h_2_to_3_percentage_overall": 75,
                    "corners_earned_2h_avg_away": 1.67,
                    "corners_earned_2h_avg_home": 2,
                    "corners_earned_2h_avg_overall": 1.75,
                    "corners_earned_2h_num_away": 5,
                    "corners_earned_2h_num_home": 2,
                    "corners_earned_2h_num_overall": 7,
                    "corners_earned_2h_over2_num_away": 0,
                    "corners_earned_2h_over2_num_home": 0,
                    "corners_earned_2h_over2_num_overall": 0,
                    "corners_earned_2h_over2_percentage_away": 0,
                    "corners_earned_2h_over2_percentage_home": 0,
                    "corners_earned_2h_over2_percentage_overall": 0,
                    "corners_earned_2h_over3_num_away": 0,
                    "corners_earned_2h_over3_num_home": 0,
                    "corners_earned_2h_over3_num_overall": 0,
                    "corners_earned_2h_over3_percentage_away": 0,
                    "corners_earned_2h_over3_percentage_home": 0,
                    "corners_earned_2h_over3_percentage_overall": 0,
                    "dangerous_attacks_num_away": 108,
                    "dangerous_attacks_num_home": 35,
                    "draw_0_10_num_away": 3,
                    "draw_0_10_num_home": 1,
                    "draw_0_10_num_overall": 4,
                    "draw_0_10_percentage_away": 100,
                    "draw_0_10_percentage_home": 50,
                    "draw_0_10_percentage_overall": 80,
                    "exact_team_goals_0_ft_away": 2,
                    "exact_team_goals_0_ft_overall": 3,
                    "exact_team_goals_0_ft_percentage_away": 67,
                    "exact_team_goals_0_ft_percentage_home": 50,
                    "exact_team_goals_0_ft_percentage_overall": 60,
                    "exact_team_goals_1_ft_away": 1,
                    "exact_team_goals_1_ft_home": 0,
                    "exact_team_goals_1_ft_overall": 1,
                    "exact_team_goals_1_ft_percentage_away": 33,
                    "exact_team_goals_1_ft_percentage_home": 0,
                    "exact_team_goals_1_ft_percentage_overall": 20,
                    "exact_team_goals_2_ft_away": 0,
                    "exact_team_goals_2_ft_home": 0,
                    "exact_team_goals_2_ft_overall": 0,
                    "exact_team_goals_2_ft_percentage_away": 0,
                    "exact_team_goals_2_ft_percentage_home": 0,
                    "exact_team_goals_2_ft_percentage_overall": 0,
                    "exact_team_goals_3_ft_away": 0,
                    "exact_team_goals_3_ft_home": 1,
                    "exact_team_goals_3_ft_overall": 1,
                    "exact_team_goals_3_ft_percentage_away": 0,
                    "exact_team_goals_3_ft_percentage_home": 50,
                    "exact_team_goals_3_ft_percentage_overall": 20,
                    "exact_total_goals_0_ft_away": 1,
                    "exact_total_goals_0_ft_home": 1,
                    "exact_total_goals_0_ft_overall": 2,
                    "exact_total_goals_1_ft_away": 1,
                    "exact_total_goals_1_ft_home": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_1_ft_overall": 1,
                    "exact_total_goals_2_ft_away": 1,
                    "exact_total_goals_2_ft_home": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_2_ft_overall": 1,
                    "exact_total_goals_3_ft_away": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_3_ft_home": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_3_ft_overall": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_4_ft_away": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_4_ft_home": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_4_ft_overall": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_5_ft_away": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_5_ft_home": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_5_ft_overall": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_6_ft_away": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_6_ft_home": 1,
                    "exact_total_goals_6_ft_overall": 1,
                    "exact_total_goals_7_ft_away": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_7_ft_home": 0,
                    "exact_total_goals_7_ft_overall": 0,
                    "fh_cards_against_avg_away": 0.33,
                    "fh_cards_against_avg_home": 0.5,
                    "fh_cards_against_avg_overall": 0.4,
                    "fh_cards_against_away": 1,
                    "fh_cards_against_home": 1,
                    "fh_cards_against_overall": 2,
                    "fh_cards_for_avg_away": 0.67,
                    "fh_cards_for_avg_home": 1.5,
                    "fh_cards_for_avg_overall": 1,
                    "fh_cards_for_away": 2,
                    "fh_cards_for_home": 3,
                    "fh_cards_for_over05_percentage_away": 33,
                    "fh_cards_for_over05_percentage_home": 100,
                    "fh_cards_for_over05_percentage_overall": 60,
                    "fh_cards_for_overall": 5,
                    "fh_cards_total_avg_away": 1,
                    "fh_cards_total_avg_home": 2,
                    "fh_cards_total_avg_overall": 1.4,
                    "fh_cards_total_away": 3,
                    "fh_cards_total_home": 4,
                    "fh_cards_total_overall": 7,
                    "fh_half_with_most_cards_total_percentage_away": 33,
                    "fh_half_with_most_cards_total_percentage_home": 50,
                    "fh_half_with_most_cards_total_percentage_overall": 40,
                    "fh_total_cards_2to3_percentage_away": 33,
                    "fh_total_cards_2to3_percentage_home": 100,
                    "fh_total_cards_2to3_percentage_overall": 60,
                    "fh_total_cards_over3_percentage_away": 0,
                    "fh_total_cards_over3_percentage_home": 0,
                    "fh_total_cards_over3_percentage_overall": 0,
                    "fh_total_cards_under2_percentage_away": 67,
                    "fh_total_cards_under2_percentage_home": 0,
                    "fh_total_cards_under2_percentage_overall": 40,
                    "formRun_away": "ddl",
                    "formRun_home": "dd",
                    "formRun_overall": "dddld",
                    "fouls_against_avg_away": 6.67,
                    "fouls_against_avg_home": 15,
                    "fouls_against_avg_overall": 8.75,
                    "fouls_against_num_away": 20,
                    "fouls_against_num_home": 15,
                    "fouls_against_num_overall": 35,
                    "fouls_recorded_away": 3,
                    "fouls_recorded_home": 1,
                    "fouls_recorded_overall": 4,
                    "freekicks_recorded_matches_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_recorded_matches_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_recorded_matches_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_avg_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_avg_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_avg_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_num_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_num_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_num_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over105_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over105_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over105_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over115_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over115_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over115_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over125_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over125_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over125_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over135_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over135_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over135_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over145_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over145_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over145_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over155_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over155_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over155_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over165_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over165_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over165_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over175_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over175_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over175_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over75_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over75_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over75_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over85_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over85_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over85_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over95_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over95_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_team_over95_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_avg_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_avg_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_avg_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_num_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_num_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_num_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over205_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over205_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over205_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over215_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over215_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over215_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over225_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over225_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over225_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over235_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over235_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over235_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over245_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over245_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over245_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over255_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over255_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over255_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over265_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over265_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over265_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over275_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over275_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over275_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over285_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over285_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over285_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over295_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over295_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over295_overall": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over305_away": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over305_home": 0,
                    "freekicks_total_over305_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_recorded_matches_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_recorded_matches_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_recorded_matches_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_avg_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_avg_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_avg_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_num_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_num_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_num_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over105_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over105_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over105_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over115_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over115_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over115_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over35_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over35_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over35_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over45_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over45_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over45_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over55_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over55_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over55_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over65_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over65_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over65_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over75_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over75_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over75_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over85_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over85_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over85_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over95_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over95_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_team_over95_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_avg_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_avg_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_avg_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_num_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_num_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_num_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over105_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over105_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over105_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over115_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over115_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over115_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over125_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over125_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over125_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over135_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over135_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over135_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over145_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over145_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over145_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over155_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over155_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over155_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over165_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over165_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over165_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over175_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over175_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over175_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over185_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over185_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over185_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over85_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over85_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over85_overall": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over95_away": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over95_home": 0,
                    "goal_kicks_total_over95_overall": 0,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_1h_num_away": 1,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_1h_num_home": 0,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_1h_num_overall": 1,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_1h_percentage_away": 33,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_1h_percentage_home": 0,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_1h_percentage_overall": 25,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_2h_num_away": 1,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_2h_num_home": 1,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_2h_num_overall": 2,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_2h_percentage_away": 33,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_2h_percentage_home": 100,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_2h_percentage_overall": 50,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_draw_num_away": 1,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_draw_num_home": 0,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_draw_num_overall": 1,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_draw_percentage_away": 33,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_draw_percentage_home": 0,
                    "half_with_most_corners_is_draw_percentage_overall": 25,
                    "half_with_most_goals_is_1h_num_away": 1,
                    "half_with_most_goals_is_1h_num_home": 1,
                    "half_with_most_goals_is_1h_num_overall": 2,
                    "half_with_most_goals_is_1h_percentage_away": 33,
                    "half_with_most_goals_is_1h_percentage_home": 50,
                    "half_with_most_goals_is_1h_percentage_overall": 40,
                    "half_with_most_goals_is_2h_num_away": 0,
                    "half_with_most_goals_is_2h_num_home": 0,
                    "half_with_most_goals_is_2h_num_overall": 0,
```

Comment: What does the first block of code have to do with the question?  What errors are you getting?  What *exactly* are you trying to extract?

Comment: show example data and expected result. And put it as text, not images. OR even better put example data as DataFrame so we could simply copy it to test solutions.

Comment: I don't know what you try to do so I only guess - probably there are to methods: (first) convert nexted dictionary to normal elements in main dictionary before you convert it to DataFrame - and this need to write all on your own (probably using some `for`-loop). (second) use `apply(pd.Series)` to convert this column to Series and later use `join()` to add this as new columns. You didn't create minimal working code which we could simply copy - so we can't create example for these methods.

Comment: @furas thanks - the example data is below the images, i could only post a section of it due to size. The image shows sections of dataframe, including the stats column that requires splitting out.

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks, the first block of code extracts the puts the data in a dataframe. Its in the data frame the issue is, there are no errors, the "stats" column requires splitting out in to a dataframe columns but not sure how to do this. The second image shows the column in my dataframe

Comment: @furas - is there a way i can add the data to this, as its bigger than the max characters pls? In the section of the data i could fit in, the column stats in the dataframe starts here - "     "stats": {.     "        The second image shows the column in my dataframe

Comment: don't put full data but only small example - and you could put it as dictionary directly in code (instead of loading from file). Create minimal working code which shows problem and we could copy and use to test solutions.

Comment: @furas thanks makes sense. The sample data is below the images on the initial post. I posted an example of the dataframe which shows the stats nested in a column on the dataframe, i managed to extract the data above the stats into individual columns.

Comment: you show some data and image but I will repeate: create minimal working code which we could simply **copy** and use to test solutions. Your data can't be simply copy. Your data needs some work to make them useful - so people give up to help you. And they downvote your question.

Comment: @furas thanks, apologies I’m new to stack flow really and not familiar with best practice and conduct for asking questions. Noted and taken on board. Thanks for your patience

Comment: if my answer resolves your problem then you can mark it as accepted and few minutes later you could upvote it (if you would have more points of reputation)

Comment: Yes, it has worked, I'm extremely helpful for your guidance and help. I will accept and upvote. Thanks and Happy New Year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar problem was few times on Stackoverflow.

---

You can use `.apply(pd.Series)`

```
stats = df['stats'].apply(pd.Series)
```

to convert dictionary in column `stats` into new `DataFrame` with all values in separated columns.

And later you can use `.join()`

```
df = df.join(stats)
```

to append these columns from new `DataFrame` to original `DataFrame`

---

I also used `del` to remove column `stats` from original `DataFrame`

---

Minimal working example which everyone can simply copy and run.

```
json = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 145,            
            "stats": {
                "AVGHT_away": 0.67,
                "AVGHT_home": 2.5,
                "AVGHT_overall": 1.4,
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 146,            
            "stats": {
                "AVGHT_away": 1.67,
                "AVGHT_home": 0.5,
                "AVGHT_overall": 3.4,
            }
        }
    ]
}

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(json["data"])

print('--- before ---')
print(df)

stats = df['stats'].apply(pd.Series)

print('--- stats ---')
print(stats)

df = df.join(stats)
del df['stats']

print('--- after ---')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- before ---
    id                                              stats
0  145  {'AVGHT_away': 0.67, 'AVGHT_home': 2.5, 'AVGHT...
1  146  {'AVGHT_away': 1.67, 'AVGHT_home': 0.5, 'AVGHT...
--- stats ---
   AVGHT_away  AVGHT_home  AVGHT_overall
0        0.67         2.5            1.4
1        1.67         0.5            3.4
--- after ---
    id  AVGHT_away  AVGHT_home  AVGHT_overall
0  145        0.67         2.5            1.4
1  146        1.67         0.5            3.4
```

---

**EDIT:**

It seems sictionary `stats` has also nested dictionary `additional_info` so you will have to repeat it for `additional_info`.

```
json = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 145,            
            "stats": {
                "AVGHT_away": 0.67,
                "AVGHT_home": 2.5,
                "additional_info": {
                    "2h_cards_against_avg_away": 1,
                    "2h_cards_against_avg_home": 1.5,
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 146,            
            "stats": {
                "AVGHT_away": 1.67,
                "AVGHT_home": 0.5,
                "additional_info": {
                    "2h_cards_against_avg_away": 1,
                    "2h_cards_against_avg_home": 1.5,
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(json["data"])

print('--- before ---')
print(df.to_string())

# ---

stats = df['stats'].apply(pd.Series)

print('--- stats ---')
print(stats.to_string())

# ---

df = df.join(stats)
del df['stats']

print('--- after ---')
print(df.to_string())

# ---

additional_info = df['additional_info'].apply(pd.Series)

print('--- additional_info ---')
print(additional_info)

# ---

df = df.join(additional_info)
del df['additional_info']

print('--- after ---')
print(df.to_string())
```

Result:

```
--- before ---
    id                                                                                                                           stats
0  145  {'AVGHT_away': 0.67, 'AVGHT_home': 2.5, 'additional_info': {'2h_cards_against_avg_away': 1, '2h_cards_against_avg_home': 1.5}}
1  146  {'AVGHT_away': 1.67, 'AVGHT_home': 0.5, 'additional_info': {'2h_cards_against_avg_away': 1, '2h_cards_against_avg_home': 1.5}}
--- stats ---
   AVGHT_away  AVGHT_home                                                     additional_info
0        0.67         2.5  {'2h_cards_against_avg_away': 1, '2h_cards_against_avg_home': 1.5}
1        1.67         0.5  {'2h_cards_against_avg_away': 1, '2h_cards_against_avg_home': 1.5}
--- after ---
    id  AVGHT_away  AVGHT_home                                                     additional_info
0  145        0.67         2.5  {'2h_cards_against_avg_away': 1, '2h_cards_against_avg_home': 1.5}
1  146        1.67         0.5  {'2h_cards_against_avg_away': 1, '2h_cards_against_avg_home': 1.5}
--- additional_info ---
   2h_cards_against_avg_away  2h_cards_against_avg_home
0                        1.0                        1.5
1                        1.0                        1.5
--- after ---
    id  AVGHT_away  AVGHT_home  2h_cards_against_avg_away  2h_cards_against_avg_home
0  145        0.67         2.5                        1.0                        1.5
1  146        1.67         0.5                        1.0                        1.5
```